# Can postgresql use console apps for calculations?

Tags: postgresql-15

I need to calculate a value for each row in my database. The calculation is quite involved, requiring lookup tables and parameters that are stored in the database too.

Now I know I can write an app, connect to the server, and calculate the value for each row - which is what I am doing now.

But is it also possible to do it the other way round? Namely, have the postgresql server pass the required info to a console app and receive the value to store? In which case you could have PostgreSQL automatically calculate the value each time a new row is inserted.

Comment: Sounds like your db/app design is not optimal.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use Triggers on Data Changes ?

Comment: @Marc: Quite possibly - but what does that have to do with the question???

Comment: @Ken: Triggers is how the calculation would be initiated - but the problem is not "how to set up a trigger" but "HOW do I get the calculation (which is done in the Console app) to run from PostgreSQL and return the value to it"?

Answer (score 0):

For This, We can use the NOTIFY and LISTEN commands in Postgres. This allows notifications to be sent to clients who are Listening and are connected to the database. So you can create a channel in your application for listening and create a trigger on insert and notify the value and the client in this case the console app to do something.

This is a good article I found how we can do this you can refer to it [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/listen-notify-automatic-client-notification-in-postgresql/)